# Clarification of Java Generation and Garbage Collector concepts?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Below are the statments i found at 
http://www.springsource.com/files/uploads/all/pdf_files/news_event/Inside_the_JVM.pdf
while going thru memory management

Statement1:-

All new objects are created in young generation
Only moved to Old Gen if they survive one or more minor GC

**Question1 :- Did not get what minor GC mean here?**

Statement2:-

Major collections occur when the tenured space fills up

**Question2:- Did not get what major collection mean here?**

As per my understanding,
all new objects are created in young generation then GC runs then deallocate the memory for the objects whose reference is not reachable
and transfer the all other objects to old generation.

**Question3 : Now when does the JVM decide to run GC on old and young generation? Does it run when young and old generation fills up the some specified space of each generation?**

**Edit** Looks like its youn generation is minor collection because its size is much less than old generation which is a major collection.This a guess. Not sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) A minor collection is a copy of object from or between the young spaces.

2) A major collection is a tidy of the old generation.

The minor collection is usually quicker than a major collection which may explain the names.

3) When copied object from the young generation fill the old gen, a full collection occurs. (The concurrent collector can trigger a major collection when it decides the old generation is a bit full)

Comment: point 1) as minor is a copy of object from or between the young spaces .How does it help in freeing up the space? As you said The minor collection is usually quicker than a major collection.Is it because of small size of objects in minor collection than major collection.Point3:- You said  If this doesn't free enough memory, a major collection is run .But major collection will free the space from old generation.For Object creation we need the space on young generation.Dont we need the minor collection for this?

Comment: Most object are short lived.  In the eden space, the retained objects are copied and the area is freed up at once.  The time it takes to do this is roughly proportional to be number of object retained.  In old generation, most objects are retained and have to be copied around the same area to avoid fragmentation. 3) more accurately a full collection occurs when the old gen fills.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is pretty long and the best answer would be to go through http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html which clearly explains all the concepts in detail.